# View does not update when some variables in @state struct changes

Tags: macos, swiftui, state

I read similar questions here, but still don't get it.

I have a struct (I've maked little changes)

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

typealias NodeID = UUID

struct Node: Identifiable {
  var id: NodeID = NodeID()
  var NodeWidth: CGFloat = 60.0
  var position: CGPoint = .zero
  var text: String = ""


  var visualID: String {
    return id.uuidString
      + "\(text.hashValue)"
  }
}
```

I have a view with a State of this struct

```
import SwiftUI

struct NodeView: View {
  
@State var node: Node
  
  var body: some View {
    Capsule()
      .fill(Color.gray)
      .frame(width: node.NodeWidth, height: 50)
  }
}
```

Have view that assemble Nodes in one view...

```
import SwiftUI

struct NodeMapView: View {
  @Binding var nodes: [Node]
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      ForEach(nodes, id: \.visualID) { node in
        NodeView(node: node)
          .offset(x: node.position.x, y: node.position.y)
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

And another view (in future will add view with links to nodes)

```
import SwiftUI

struct GraphView: View {
  @ObservedObject var mech: Mechanics
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      //add links view 
      NodeMapView(selection: selection, nodes: $mech.nodes)
    }
  }
}
```

And I have several functions in class Mechanics

```
    import Foundation
    import CoreGraphics
    
    class Mechanics: ObservableObject {
      
      let rootNodeID: NodeID
      @Published var nodes: [Node] = []
      
      init() {
        let root = Node(text: "root")
        rootNodeID = root.id
        addNode(root)
      }
      
      func rootNode() -> Node {
        guard let root = nodes.filter({ $0.id == rootNodeID }).first else {
          fatalError("mechanics failure: no root node")
        }
        return root
      }
      
      func replace(_ OldNode: Node, with NewNode: Node) {
        var newSet = nodes.filter { $0.id != OldNode.id }
        newSet.append(NewNode)
        nodes = newSet
      }
    }
    extension Mechanics {
     func updateNodeText(_ srcNode: Node, string: String) {
            var newNode = srcNode
            newNode.text = string
            replace(srcNode, with: newNode)
          }
        
          func updateNodeWidth(_ srcNode: Node, string: String) {
            var newNode = srcNode
            if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: string) {
              newNode.NodeWidth = CGFloat(truncating: n)
            }
            replace(srcNode, with: newNode)
          }
         
          func updatePosX(_ srcNode: Node, string: String) {
            var newNode = srcNode
            if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: string) {
              newNode.position.x = CGFloat(truncating: n)
            }
            replace(srcNode, with: newNode)
          }
    }
```

Last view is

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct SurfaceView: View {
      @ObservedObject var mesh: Mechanics
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
          Rectangle().fill(Color(red: 154/255, green: 154/255, blue: 154/255))
          GraphView(mech: self.mesh)
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.1))
            }//zstack
        }//geometryreader
    }//vstack
}//body end
}//view end
```

And the problem is:
When I use updateNodeText or updatePosX functions - View has been changed - all OK, but when I use updateNodeWidth function nothing happens.
Parameters were changed, I can see it in text fields, but view has not.

What I am doing wrong?

Update: While debugging I found out that in NodeView struct parametrs is unchanged (i dont know why) but when I'm in function parameters are correct. But when I use updateNodeText function parameters in NodeView updated to normal.

Update2: till debug I've found out that variables in cycle ForEach of NodeMapView displayed correctly but when I go into NodeView all variables displayed wrong (outdated data)

Comment: Show the full (not working) code please.

Comment: Please try to turn your example into a minimal, reproducible example!

Comment: Try marking `MyVal` or `position` with `@State`

Comment: @CharlieReeder Not an option (due code specifics). 
I tried to describe the problem in more detail (post was edited)

Comment: @LouisLac the full code is very large so I tried to highlight the main part

Comment: I see few problems here. First, the `NodeView` struct uses `@State` for node but you did not provided an initial value. This should be the case since `@State` means the view owns the data. If the view does not owns the data it uses you should use `@Binding` (when mutation is needed) or a plain let property (when no mutation is needed). Second, you should show us where and how you instantiate `NodeMapView` so we can see where the nodes come from. Lastly, show us the `replace` method.

Comment: @LouisLac Add to post all you ask about. Hope it helps...

Comment: Can you try replacing all `if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: )` by an assert of a force unwrap to make sure that the functions succeed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** It looks like you are using `@State` incorrectly in `NodeView`. Changing the line to `let node: Node` should solve the issue.

## Details

In SwiftUI views react to changes in their state. Moreover a view can either own its state or reference some state it does not own. This functioning ensures that there is a unique source of truth for the state triggering view updates.

SwiftUI provide few mechanisms to declare states that are owned or not by a view.

Firstly, owned states can be declared in different ways depending on the state data type (value type vs reference type such as classes) and mutability. They have in common that **they must be initialized to some value in the view itself** (in the `init`) since by definition the view own the state and must not acquire it from an external dependency. These include:

- `@State` for value types (`Int`, `Double`, `String`, ...),
- `@StateObject` for reference types (classes declared as `ObservableObject`).

Here is an example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Node {
  var text: String
}

// NodeView owns and can mutate its node state
struct NodeView: View {
  @State private var node = Node(text: "root")
  
  var body: some View {
    Text(node.text)
  }
}
```

You should declare owned state as private to prevent issues such as breaking the unique source of truth rule.

Secondly, **unowned** state works the opposite of owned state: it should not be initialized by the view itself (the state is passed from another view / retrieved from the environment) and thus should not be declared private in general. Several methods exist depending on the data type and mutability (not exhaustive):

- Plain `let` properties, for immutable unowned state,
- `@Binding` for value types unowned state,
- `@ObservedObject` for reference types injected by a parent view and
- `@EnvironmentObject` for a reference type injected through the environment.

Here are some examples:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Node {
  var text: String
}

// `NodeView` cannot mutate `node` and does not own this state...
struct NodeView: View {
  let node: Node
  
  var body: some View {
    Text(node.text)
  }
}

// ... since it is owned by `ContentView` and is the unique source of truth
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var node = Node(text: "root")

  var body: some View {
    NodeView(node: node)
  }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Node {
  var text: String
}

// `NodeView` can mutate this shared state...
struct NodeView: View {
  @Binding var node: Node
  
  var body: some View {
    Text(node.text)
      .onTapGesture {
        node.text.append("!")
      }
  }
}

// ... which is owned by `ContentView` 
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var node = Node(text: "root")

  var body: some View {
    NodeView(node: node)
  }
}
```

To go back to your code, the `node` property of your `NodeView` should not be annotated with `@State` since the state is owned by the `Mechanics` object (which you'll probably instantiate in a parent view of `SurfaceView` as a `@StateObject`). Since there is no mutation, it should be a plain let property here, and if you need mutation it should be a `@Binding` since `Node` is a value type (struct).

I tested your code with this fix and it solved the issue.